# How to generate an executable .sh file with Gradle?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, gradle, build.gradle

I have a Java project in Eclipse. It works fine and I can run it from cmd using java -jar sample-app.jar

I now have to use Gradle to produce an executable `sh` file for use in Linux. 
I've found some resources on creating start scripts but the most I've managed to do is use the standard *'startScripts'* task to create a sample.app.bat file.

I've scoured question after question and page after page on google to try and find an answer and I'm not having much luck. I've also read through the Gradle Application plugin documentation a number of times and still quite confused.

How do I write a Gradle task to generate an `sh` file to execute my sample-app.jar file?

**Note:** The sample-app.bat file does no execute. It only produces an "Error: Cannot find or load main class com.sample.MainClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that mentioned [application](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) plugin is what you're looking for. [Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/41712119) you can find a little demo. Now to run main class you need to run `gradle run`. To prepare *sh* and *bat* scripts run gradle `gradle startScripts`. To prepare a runnable (and easily copyable) version of application and starts scripts run `gradle distZip` or `gradle distTar`. Both tasks will prepare and archive that can be extracted to given directory and run with prepared script. The last task `gradle installDist` will prepare both script and executable jar in a given directory but without packing them.

All artifacts created with `dist*`, `installDist` and `startScripts` can be found under `build` directory. Try running:

```
gradle clean distZip distTar installDist
```

and then `tree -a build` to view all prepared filed.

To run main class from the prepared jar remember to execute shell scripts in the correct directory, e.g.: `build/install/lol/bin`.

Comment: Thank you. I was creating the execution script the whole time, just wasn't aware that I was doing it. Your answer has certainly helped clear up my confusion. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm now finding that all of my applications cannot be executed using the generated batch file. It was working this morning when i initially replied, now they were not. No changes to the code have been made since. 

I'm getting the error;
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.Main

Comment: @Afterfield I guess it all runs correctly - have you configured main class? Also, please remember that you need to run the script from the valid location.

Comment: Turns out I completely misunderstood which files were being built. I was trying to execute the project files created by Gradle, not the ones compiled and zipped for distribution. This was causing a number of errors regarding not being able to find classes and libraries, despite everything being configured correctly. Running the execution scripts from the .zip file works perfectly and I've had no problems since.

Comment: @Opal is the similar functionality, I mean creating binaries is available in `maven` world

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard Gradle way how to do it. You must start your `gradle.build` by

```
apply plugin: 'application'
```

After that, you can launch `distTar`, `distZip`, and `installZip` tasks. (They lie in `distribution` task folder). Each of them creates the `build/scripts` folder in your project and puts windows and Linux scripts there.  Also, they create tar/zip/folder installation - look at the `distribution` plugin.

Notice, you don't need to apply the `distribution` plugin - it is in the 'application' plugin already. And the `startScripts` plugin is in the `distribution` plugin.

But the situation is not so nice. The second problem is that the generated scripts are bad. At least that for Windows. So, you will have to edit them by hand or automate the process in the script inserted in `startScripts`. It will look so:

```
startScripts {
    doLast {
         your script editing lines here. 
    }
}
```